# Connected and Hausdorff topological space whose topology is stable under countable intersection,

Tags: general-topology

We know that the converging sequences of a discrete space are the stationary sequences.

I am looking for two examples for spaces (not empty or reduced to a singleton)

1. connected and Hausdorff topological space where the converging sequences are the stationary sequences.
2. connected and Hausdorff topological space whose topology is stable under countable intersection.

Comment: What do you mean by *separate*? That is not a standard term.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Hausdorff space  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space

Comment: And by *stable under countable intersection* you mean that $G_\delta$-sets are open?

Comment: Exactly: $G_\delta$ sets are open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example in Arvind K. Misra, *A topological view of P-spaces*, General Topology and its Applications, Volume 2, Issue 4, December 1972, 349-362. It starts with the space $E_0$ that he constructs in **Example** $\bf{3.1}$, a Hausdorff $P$-space (i.e., one in which $G_\delta$-sets are open) with two points $a$ and $b$ that cannot be separated by a continuous function. In **Example** $\bf{5.3}$ he recursively constructs from $E_0$ spaces $E_n$ for $n\in\omega$ in such a way that $E_n$ is embedded in $E_{n+1}$ and then defines $E_\omega$ to be the [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) of the sequence $\langle E_n:n\in\omega\rangle$. (The topology on $E_\omega$ is the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) determined by the embeddings.) $E_\omega$ is a Hausdorff $P$-space on which every real-valued continuous function is constant, so it is connected.

In any $P$-space every convergent sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: M.Scott A Big Thank's

Comment: @cerise: You’re very welcome. And I just realized that I accidentally omitted the [link to the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X72900268).